# Spring 3 MVC Validation with Hibernate, error after hasErrors?

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

I am just learning Spring3 Validation with Hibernate.  I have this class but I am setting getting the following error

org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.stutteringjohnsmith.model.Friend

I am doing the sample from

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/web/spring-3-mvc-and-hibernate3-example-part1.html

but I change the Article to Friend!  Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely problem is that there is still a reference to the "Article" in the code that has not been updated to "Friend". I would try searching all the files for "Article" and update as required. Have you changed the `<property name="annotatedClasses">` section in the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file for example?

Also you might want accept answers to your questions otherwise it might put people off helping you out!